# asp.net mvc 4 set viewbag to link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I get variable as `@ViewBag.confile` from controller to view it works but i put it into link but i don't  show  but i outside of link it show correctly.
i want to add this  `@ViewBag.confile` variable into a `href tag`  what is error in my code.how can i achieve this here is my code

i am using asp.net mvc 4

```
<a href="http://localhost:64049/Content/" @ViewBag.confile >Download Converted File          @ViewBag.confile</a>
```

@ViewBag.confile variable is show correctly in view but problem is when i click link i do HTTP `Error 403.14 - Forbidden error` web browser address bar show only `http://localhost:64049/Content/`
`@ViewBag.confile` variable is missing

Comment: glad that it worked for you..thankz...

Comment: it's a correct answer i don't know why someone downvoted...thankz...

Comment: No @Saranga...it was a simple question why should i do a edit...no..

Comment: @Saranga...i m here to help others i m not here to fight with one another..if i m wrong here..then i m sorry..thankzz...

Comment: why you are blaming ..i don't accept such a thing

Comment: @srinathmadusanka...sorry but i not blaming anyone...as you can see i m polite saranga is giving harsh comments..thankzz...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work :

```
<a href="http://localhost:64049/Content/@(ViewBag.confile)">Download Converted File @(ViewBag.confile)</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using the tilda syntax to allow MVC to resolve the reference:

```
<a href="~/Content/@( ViewBag.confile )">Download Converted File @ViewBag.confile</a>
```